# I have a "restart to..." button on the power off panel, but it won't work

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to enable this button so that I can choose to reboot to windows, but it won't work as expected.

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot of Power Off dialog]

And after I click the “Restart to...” button, there's a little comment box coming in the upper-left corner of the screen.

[image: screenshot of empty window at top of screen]

I was expecting that once I click it, there will be a list of entries that I can click and reboot to. Could someone help me with this? Thanks!